# How to remove elements that are not inside another element?

Tags: jquery

I have a gallery page on Wordpress that every time I add an image via the visual editor (the html editor is not an option for my client) Wordpress adds `<br />` tags which mess with the layout. The only way that I can think of how to fix this is by removing them with jQuery. However I do not know how to remove only the elements I need. Here is a similar structure:

```
<div id="content">
 <div class="wp-caption">
  <img>
   <p> I need to <br /> keep this break <p>
  </div>  
   <br />  <!-- remove this -->
 <div class="wp-caption">
  <img>
   <p> I need to <br /> keep this break <p>
  </div>
<div>
```

Now with jQuery I can do this:

```
$("#content br").remove();
```

This removes even the `<br />` within the `wp-content`. Is there a way to filter them out?

Comment: Ok, here we see the `<br>` that should be kept, but what about those to _be_ removed?

Comment: Can you give us an example of where the unwanted `<br />` tags are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#content > br').remove();` or `$('#content').children('br').remove()` will remove only the `<br />` tags that are direct children of `#content`.

Comment: that worked for me, I wanted exactly that, the children of the #content and not the br within the .wp-caption - I need to wait to tick it